# Facebook Web SDK for login Resize

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have used Facebook WEB SDK for LOGIN in ROR web application, login popup is what i am getting is in small size, so from background i can use the app without login to facebook, I want to change the width and height of popup so that it should restrict the app from background?Does any know about it, please let me know.

Comment: Could you share your code so far so we can see what you've been up to?

Comment: _“so from background i can use the app without login to facebook”_ – if you don’t want that to be possible, then you should fix this within your app.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, you are right. that fixed my issue.